# Easing function object goes too fast

Tags: javascript, animation, math

I recently came across this website which contains some easing functions: http://gizma.com/easing/

And have tried to implement a `quadratic easing in/out` from it, into my script but my sprite seems to whiz off the screen super quickly. I'm not sure where my logic went wrong and need some help understanding my mistake.

My easing function looks like this:

```
    //t = time, b = startvalue, c = change in value
     function ease(t, b, c, duration) {
         t /= duration/2; //duration is in milliseconds
         if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
         t--;
         return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
     };
```

And my code to animate the motion is fired from a `mousedown` listener:

```
function animate(e){
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var duration  = 2000; //2 seconds

    var startX    = camera.x;
    var startY    = camera.y;

    var targetX   = e.offsetX - element.width/2  + camera.x; //world space
    var targetY   = e.offsetY - element.height/2 + camera.y; //world space

    var vectorX   = targetX - startX / duration;
    var vectorY   = targetY - startY / duration;

    var startTime = Date.now();

    function update(){
        var t   = Date.now() - startTime; //time elapsed so far
        var cX  = vectorX * t; //change in X
        var cY  = vectorY * t; //change in Y

        var amountX = ease(t,startX,cX,duration); // see function above
        var amountY = ease(t,startY,cY,duration);

        var difX    = startX - amountX; //get the difference
        var difY    = startY - amountY;

            camera.x += difX;
            camera.y += difY;

        if (t >= duration){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        } else {
            timer = setTimeout(update,0);               
        }
    }
    update();   
}
```

What's causing the animation to go so quickly and so far?

Edit: added, a fiddle encase it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/a86m33nj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/pcconsolidated/xesnom2t/

Your problem was just simply over complicating it. The quadratic easement function simply wanted to know the start coordinate, how far to move it,the current time relative to the start time, and the overall duration. Also the output from the quadratic is the new coordinate not how far the object is being moved so simply replace the coordinate with the value from the function rounded to the nearest number.

```js
var element   = document.getElementById('background');
var output       = document.getElementById('output');
var camera=document.getElementById("camera");
var timer;
var targetX=0;
var targetY=0;
document.addEventListener('click', animate,true);
var duration  = 2000; //2 seconds
var startX    = 0;
var startY    = 0;
var startTime =0;


function animate(e){
 targetX   = e.clientX ;
    targetY   = e.clientY ;
 clearTimeout(timer);
     startX    = parseInt(camera.style.left.split("p")[0]);
  startY    = parseInt(camera.style.top.split("p")[0]);
  
 startTime = Date.now();
     
    
 
   
 
  updateLoc(); 
 }
 


 function updateLoc(){
   var t = (Date.now() - startTime);
   var cX  = targetX-startX; //change in X
   var cY  = targetY-startY; //change in Y
            
   var amountX = ease(t,startX,cX,duration);
   var amountY = ease(t,startY,cY,duration);
               
    newX=Math.floor(amountX);
    newY=Math.floor(amountY);
    camera.style.left = Math.floor(newX)+"px";
             camera.style.top = Math.floor(newY)+"px";
    output.innerHTML+=newX+","+newY+"___";
   if (Date.now() - startTime >= duration){
    clearTimeout(timer);
   } else {
    timer = setTimeout(updateLoc,0);    
   }
  }


 
 //t = time, b = startvalue, c = change in value
   function ease(t, b, c,duration) {
    t /= duration/2;
    if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
    t--;
    return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
   };


</script>
```

```html
<canvas id="background" width="500" height="500">
    
    
    
</canvas><br/>
<div id="output"></div><div id="camera" style="background-color:green;top:250px;left:150px;position:absolute;height:30px;width:30px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

It's quite ruff and my offset is wrong somwhere but ill continue to tinker after dinner and see if i can get that. Here is my code hope it works for you.

Comment: Why doesn't it ? Seems to on my screen. After all, i would get an error if not. Did you not look at the JSFiddle?

Comment: It's declared just don't see it being called

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking at??

Comment: never mind i found it for some reason find didnt get it inside fiddle. sorry

Comment: Just edited my response. You can slow your quadratic formula by reducing the impact of time through scaling the value of T

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, how would that fix the problem other than simply cause the animation to run half the speed, it would still have the problem only slower..

Comment: Sorry, i thought this was the issue that it was to quick. What exactly are you looking for this to do.

Comment: When you click on the screen the camera is meant to ease to that location with the specified duration.

Comment: Okay. Im sorry i completely misunderstood the question. I'll look and try again.

Comment: It's fixed, just have offsets wrong somewhere which im sure you can figure out, or when i get back from dinner I can as well.

Comment: I'm confused why you're not using canvas, but instead manipulating elements which is not going to make anysense when we are talking about camera offsets and world space co ordinates, how can you be sure it's using world space or not ?

Comment: I got everything from positions within the window with this. Was just easier, if you go by the canvas space then just need to get the offsets of canvas relative to the window.

Comment: Sec, just trying to edit my original script with your version to see if it works.

Comment: Alright. I have also fixed the offset issue. The output from the quadratic easment shouldnt be used added to the existing location but instead replaces the location. have eddited fiddle and edditing code above

Comment: would there be any way to get the difference from each frame as my main code updates camera by amount rather than by setting it to a specific location?

Comment: The output from the easement function is the new X or Y value. if you need to pass a relative change to your Draw function(if your still going at it that way rather than moving an element)  you will need to calculate the new location from the new absolute location the easement gives you. However i feel it may be easier to keep the absolute location and change your Draw() to accept absolute rather than relative

Comment: My function works :) Thank you for the help, also welcome to SO !

Comment: No problem dave. Just remember KISS(Keep It Simple Stupid) you were just overthinking it and made it far to complicated! Please dont forget to vote me up and choose my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after playing with your code I made it work. Now camera will follow wherever you clicked:

```
   function animate(e){
    clearTimeout(timer);

    var duration  = 2000; //2 seconds

    var startX    = camera.x;
    var startY    = camera.y;

    var targetX   = e.offsetX - element.width/2  + camera.x;
    var targetY   = e.offsetY - element.height/2 + camera.y;

    var startTime = Date.now();

    //t = time, b = startvalue, c = change in value
     function ease(t, b, c,duration) {
         t /= duration/2;
         if (t < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
         t--;
         return -c/2 * (t*(t-2) - 1) + b;
     };

    function update(){
        var t   = (Date.now() - startTime);
        var cX  = -targetX; //change in X
        var cY  = -targetY; //change in Y

        camera.x = ease(t,startX,cX,duration);
        camera.y = ease(t,startY,cY,duration);

        if (Date.now() - startTime > duration){
            clearTimeout(timer);
        } else {
            timer = setTimeout(update,10);              
        }
    }    
    update();   
}
```

I hope it helped. Cheers!

Comment: I am using deltaTime the iteration speed should be irrelevant.

Comment: @OddOrbStudio this was a part of the problem, in addition to the output needed to be treated as absolute not relative, and the declarations of start and target changed